# Need to do dynamic type assertion to interface

Tags: go, interface

I would like to copy the values from one struct to another. I will be using this function many times and each time object of different struct types are passed. So I use a generic `interface{}` type as the arguments of the function.

For reference, please look this code https://play.golang.org/p/d6JDySAU0v

```
func CopyStruct(oldValue interface{}, newValue interface{}) interface{} {
   /*Please do note that the arguments oldValue and newValue of CopyStruct function is 
      of different struct types.*/     
            oldReflect := reflect.ValueOf(oldValue)
            newReflect := reflect.ValueOf(newValue)
            newReflectAdd := reflect.ValueOf(&newValue)

            for i := 0; i < oldReflect.NumField(); i++ {
                field := oldReflect.Field(i)
                ValueType := oldReflect.Type().Field(i)
                for j := 0; j < newReflect.NumField(); j++ {

                    newType := newReflect.Type().Field(j)
                    switch field.Kind() {
                    case reflect.String:
                         if ValueType.Name == newType.Name {                           
                               newReflect.Elem().FieldByName(newType.Name).SetString(field.String())
                        }       
                    case reflect.Int:
                        if ValueType.Name == newType.Name {
                              newReflectAdd.Elem().FieldByName(newType.Name).SetInt(field.Int())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return newReflectAdd
        }
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
Handler crashed with error reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on interface Value
```

It seems the error is the following line:

```
newReflectAdd.Elem().FieldByName(newType.Name).SetString(field.String())
```

But if I use type assertion for `newValue` before this line then there is no error.

```
typeAssert := newValue.(Info)
newReflectAdd := reflect.ValueOf(&typeAssert)
```

Since I am going to use this function as generic for many struct types I don't know how to type assert dynamically.

Comment: Writing your own "generic" CopyStruct when a simple `a=b` would do seems rather strange.

Comment: but this a and b are of different struct type.So i cannot use a=b....

Comment: i have added the sample code in go playgroundThanks

Comment: Okay, I understand. This is not a copy so you should not call it a copy. Note that this is a difficult task. Please read https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection _at_ _least_ _twice_ and make sure you understand every word in there. Then note that two nested loops over the fields is overkill and probably wrong: Iterate once, find the field by name and set it. Also note that you _do_ _not_ need to type assert stuff here, all you need is the right level of indirection.

Comment: Shameless plug: Take a look at https://github.com/vdobler/ht/tree/master/populate how copying one structure into an other structure can be done. Note especially how https://github.com/vdobler/ht/blob/master/populate/populate.go#L277 handles interface values and pointers.

Comment: Also note that Go convention is to have the destination argument be first, and the source argument second--opposite of what you've done.